# Default values for record types

Tags: f#, json.net

Suppose I have a record type:

```
type CountHolder = { Counter: int}
type NameCount = { Name: string; Count: CountHolder}
```

I'm am looking for way to specify a default value for the `Count` property when deserializing either of the following json strings (using JSON.NET):

```
{"Name":"My Name","Count": null}
{"Name":"My Name"}
```

For example, my default value could be defined as

```
{ Counter :  0 }
```

If I could find an extension point in the JSON.NET serialization pipeline that would allow me to define a default value at runtime, I'm guessing that could solve my problem.

**EDIT**

In response to [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29701883/2382536) suggesting that I modify my record type to make the `Count` field optional - I would rather not do this as my type is consumed by C# code.  By making this field optional consumers of my code would be forced in to taking on a dependency on `FSharp.Core`.

Answer (score 1):

You could always define `NameCount` thusly:

```
type NameCount = { Name: string; Count: CountHolder option }
```

And then deal with the `None`.

Comment: +1 if it is valid for Count to be missing/null, then it should be represented by an option. If it's not valid, then this is a bug in whatever code is serializing NameCount without a value for Count.

Comment: Good idea - but see the edit to my question. Currently the interface I expose does not require consumers to take on any additional references.  I would prefer to keep things this way!